# opnet simulation

Tags: simulation, simulator

Using `OPNET` to simulate a project and when I make run for simulation, this error came up. please how can I solve it?

```
<<< Recoverable Error >>>                                                   |
| Process model (aodv_rte) compilation failed                                 |
| Errors given in file (C:\Users\Administrator\op_admin\tmp\cc_err_5640)
```

Answer (score 0):

open a new project then press Edit > preferences  then search for network then scroll down for a label "Discrete event simulation you will find below it " Network simulation Repositories " 
its value is 0 for default set its value "stdmod" and press apply and then ok thats it your simulation will work fine now :)